# Android-Java | SimpleDateFormat & URL change chars depending on device language

Tags: java, android, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have an android app in which I send logs to a logstash server.

To create the index I use a static string identifier and current date:

> indexofapp-20170823

But for some reason, sometimes the index arrive with strange characters in the date:

> indexofapp-ￛﾲￛﾰￛﾱￛﾷￛﾰￛﾶￛﾱￛﾲ

This is the way I am constructing the date and the URL:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ");

df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
String date = df.format(new Date());

String urlString = Values.URL.ELASTICACHE;

URL url = new URL(urlString + "/indexofapp-" + date + "/" + logType + "/");
```

My suspicion is that maybe some android devices configured in another languages are changing the characters...this is breaking our log server, any help?

Comment: Have you try to pass Locale.ENGLISH into SimpleDateFormat constructor like - new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ", Locale.ENGLISH) ?

Comment: if you dont use first line of SimpleDateFormat,then remove it.
DateFormat df= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd", Locale.ENGLISH);
String date = df.format(new Date());

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create the index yourself, logstash creates it for you if it does not exist.

Here is a sample logstash configuration to achieve that

```
input {
  <Your Input Plugin>
}

filter {
  <Optional Filters>
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["<Elasticsearch IP>:<Elasticsearch Port>"]
    index => "indexofapp-%{+YYYYMMdd}"
  }
}
```

See [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html) for details